# Install recessed lights and chandelier with 3-way switches

Tags: electrical, wiring, planning

I am remodeling my entry way and dining room to give a more open feel.

Existing:

- 15 Amp breaker
- 12-2 Feed directly from the box
- two gang box outside of the kitchen

  - 1 standard switch and 1 three way (chandalier turns on and off from entry and kitchen and the can lights only turn on from the kitchen)
  - 12-3 wire connecting switches and running to chandelier

    - 12-3 wire running from chandalier to can lights
  - 12-3 wire from switches to entry door(Entry switch only turns on chandalier and not can lights.

The chandelier and can lights are not centered in the room which is odd as there was not issue with the joist spacing above. The first project is to center the chandelier. From there I am removing the two can lights in the center of the room and adding four in the corner. (Since opening walls the entry is a little dim).  I am also looking to add a double 3 way switch to the entry way.

[Link to Double Three Way](https://www.emisupply.com/catalog/leviton-5243w-duplex-style-3way3way-combination-switch-120277-volt-white-p-24766.html?utm_source=googprod&utm_medium=product_search&utm_campaign=google-product-search-us-en&utm_term=LEV-5243-W&gclid=Cj0KEQjw7LS6BRDo2Iz23au25OQBEiQAQa6hwPXnZ9OvQmvecl24BDwEdYOvFnWUX2H_6MhFoF0qY_0aAu8l8P8HAQ#.V036CPkrJaQ)
 This will allow the canned lights and chandelier to be turned on from the kitchen side or the entry box. Due to the revised spacing I need to run all new wires. I went ahead and removed everything above the ceiling.

I plan on running the wires like this diagram: 
[Link to Wiring Diagram](http://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/wiring-diagrams-3way-7.html)

I plan on replacing the wire with 14-3 since the breaker is so close and I am not running much off the lines.This would require the following:

- Two lines from the kitchen box to the entry box for the 3 way switches.
- 1 line from the kitchen box to the chandelier
- 1 second line from the kitchen box to the can lights.

Do you think this is the correct approach or is there a way to run 1 line from the kitchen box to the entry box to control? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Don't use 14/3 if you have 12/2 coming from the panel. It's a bad idea to downsize wire in most cases. A person could see the #12 at the panel and conclude that it's safe to upgrade the breaker to 20A.

Comment: Are the switch boxes metal or plastic?

Comment: The switch boxes are plastic and the chandelier and can lights are all metal

Comment: Are all the switches located within the dining room?

Comment: Essentially yes but there is one switch box near the entry door and another box near the kitchen. My objective is to be able to turn on the can lights independent of the chandelier and to be able to switch on either the chandelier or pot lights from either side of the room

Comment: @Isherwood, thank you for the insight. I went back into my breaker box and noticed it was a 20A breaker! 100 bucks later I now have 100ft of 12-3 and 12-2 ready to go.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your plan will work now that you have the 12/3 cable -- since you have a neutral at the kitchen-side switch, you don't need to worry about running one to the entry-side switch, as the 404.2(C) provisions for neutral at switches only require neutral at one location within a multiway switching setup.